# writing in text file in java

Tags: java, string, file, file-io

I have a text file that contained a large number of words, and i want to divide the words by writing ** for every 4 words.
What i did until now is adding the first ** ( the first 4 words) and I have some difficulties in putting the other stars.

here is my code until now (I am using java)

```
import java.io.*;

public class Insert {

 public static void main(String args[]){
     try {
       INSERT In = new INSERT();
       int tc=4;

       In.insertStringInFile (new File("D:/Users//im080828/Desktop/Souad/project/reduction/weight/outdata/d.txt"), tc, "**");
       }
     catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       }
 }


 public void insertStringInFile(File inFile, int lineno, String lineToBeInserted) 
   throws Exception {
 // temp file
 File outFile = new File("$$$$$$$$.tmp");

 // input
 FileInputStream fis  = new FileInputStream(inFile);
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader
     (new InputStreamReader(fis));

 // output         
 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
 PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fos);

 String thisLine = "";
 int i =1;
 while ((thisLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
   if(i == lineno) out.println(lineToBeInserted);
   out.println(thisLine);
   i++;
   }
out.flush();
out.close();
in.close();

inFile.delete();
outFile.renameTo(inFile);
 }
}
```

Please.. give me some ideas

Thanks :)

Comment: I just fixed it @Sachin sharma

Comment: Java is case-sensitive so your code still would not work but the right answer to your question was posted anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `if (i == lineno)` you only get true `if (i==4)`, so your behavior is normal. You need to use the modulo operator `if ((i % lineno) == 0)`  to get a star every for lines. 
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/273783-the-use-of-the-modulo-operator/